# Having trouble getting the correct search suggestions for Icelandic letters?

Tags: android, here-api

Using the HERE Android SDK, I'm having trouble getting search suggestions `(TextSuggestionRequest(string))` for special characters, e.g. `'Þ'` in `Þrastarhöfði` or `'Æ'` in `Ægisgata`. Can anyone suggest a way to get around this problem, perhaps if I convert my Strings in someway before searching?

Comment: Define the problem more precisely. Do you want `Æ` to match ae? If the user actually types those specials characters I don't see how that could cause a problem

Comment: Online or offline search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest HERE Android SDK has introduced an TextAutoSuggestionRequest API which has improved language support. This search request perform similar functionality to the TextSuggestionRequest, but the returned items contain additional location information... instead of just strings.